# How to run test after some other test?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I've made rspec extension that makes and loads db dumps.

Usage example:

- one test makes order and populates db
- and I want to test admin page after making order

Right now I'm using it like this:

```
# spec/support/config/db_dumper.rb
module DbDumper
  def make_dump(name)
    assert_executable('pg_dump')

    path = dump_path(name)

    FileUtils.mkdir_p(File.dirname(path))

    options = [
      # '--verbose',
      '--clean',
      '--no-owner',
      '--no-acl',
      '--format=c',
      "--dbname=#{ENV['DATABASE_URL']}"
    ].join(' ')

    cmd = "pg_dump #{options} > #{path}"

    puts "Make dump with: #{cmd}"
    system cmd
  end

  def load_dump(name)
    assert_executable('pg_restore')

    path = dump_path(name)

    options = [
      # '--verbose',
      '--clean',
      '--no-owner',
      '--no-acl',
      '--format=c',
      "--dbname=#{ENV['DATABASE_URL']}"
    ].join(' ')

    cmd = "pg_restore #{options} #{path}"

    puts "Restore dump with: #{cmd}"
    system cmd
  end

  def dump_exists(name)
    path = dump_path(name)
    File.exist?(path)
  end

  private

  def dump_path(name)
    file = "#{name}.dump"
    Rails.root.join('spec', 'fixtures', 'dumps', file)
  end

  def assert_executable(name)
    present = `which #{name}`.strip.present?
    raise "No executable #{name}" unless present
  end
end

RSpec.configure do |c|
  c.include DbDumper
end

RSpec.configure do |c|
  c.include DbDumper
end

# spec/features/checkout_spec.rb
feature 'Checkout page' do
  scenario 'can make order' do
    # ... make order
    make_dump('checkout')
  end
end

# spec/features/admin_spec.rb
feature 'Admin page' do
  before { load_dump('checkout') }
  scenario 'shows order' do
    # ... test
  end
end
```

But I want to write something like this

```
# spec/features/checkout_spec.rb
feature 'Checkout page' do
  scenario 'can make order', id: 'checkout' do
    # ... make order
  end
end

# spec/features/admin_spec.rb
feature 'Admin page' do
  scenario 'shows order', after: 'checkout' do
    # ... test
  end
end
```

Pseudocode for this

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.after(:example, :id) do
    id = example.metadata[:id]
    make_dump(id)
  end

  config.prepend_before(:example, :after) do
    id = example.metadata[:after]

    unless dump_exists(id)
      # run test with id, this test will make dump
    end

    load_dump(id)
  end
end
```

But running some other test withing before hook is bad and probably impossible. Can someone help me?

Comment: Just don't. State-dependency between tests is a known code smell.

Comment: @CodeGnome ok, I think you right. I just had a vision. The reason to make this was to mitigate creation of the model object (order for example), that requires the long trail of other objects. But sharing dumps between tests is not flexible. Running service that creates a required object directly - too. I know what to do - I will get rid of factory_bot, I will use seed_dump at the end of test to make a snapshot, then I will copy-paste this snapshot to the beginning of other test with modifications.